# Hamcrest's closeTo is not available to use

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, gradle, hamcrest

`closeTo` method of hamcrest is not available for me to use in Eclipse. Other methods like `is`, `iscloseto` are available.

I am beginning to learn Spring and following a video tutorial. In it the instructor is using `closeTo` inside `is` to test a method. It does not work for me. The gradle dependency is there.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type the full qualified name `Matchers.closeTo` which should work.

If you want to just type `closeTo` and get Eclipse to suggest you the available methods , you have to configure static import in Eclipse first. Add `org.hamcrest.Matchers.*` to the Favorites  (See [this](http://www.greghaskins.com/archive/eclipse-favorites-to-make-your-tdd-life-easier)):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Why did Eclipse not do it by itself?